# .NET: How does the EventHandler race-condition fix work?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

There's the following pattern which is used to avoid a race condition when raising events in case another thread unsubscribes from MyEvent, making it null.

```
class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void F()
    {
        EventHandler handler = MyEvent;
        if(handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

as opposed to the wrong way of doing it which is prone to this race condition:

```
class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void F()
    {
        if(MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

My question is, given that `System.Delegate` is a reference type: in case MyEvent is not null, how come

```
EventHandler handler = MyEvent;
```

seems to *copy* its invocation list instead of *obtaining* the reference.

I would expect that having the MyEvent delegate assigned to the 'handler' variable, then once somebody *changed* MyEvent that the object that 'handler' references would be changed as well.

Obviously, that is not the case, otherwise this nifty little pattern wouldn't work.

I've looked into the .NET source code and still could not find my answer there (it's probably there, but I've looked for about an hour and couldn't find it, so here I am.)
I've also read what the C# Language Specification has to say about events and delegates, but it doesn't address this matter.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would expect that once I got the
>   MyEvent delegate inside the 'handler'
>   reference, once somebody would change
>   MyEvent that the object that 'handler'
>   references will be changed as well.
>   [..]
>   Notice that System.Delegate is a class and not a struct.

Although you are correct that delegate-types are references-types, they are *immutable* reference-types. From [**`System.Delegate`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx):

> "Delegates are immutable; **once
>   created, the invocation list of a
>   delegate does not change.**[...]
>   Combining operations, such as Combine
>   and Remove, do not alter existing
>   delegates. Instead, such an
>   operation returns a new delegate that
>   contains the results of the operation,
>   an unchanged delegate, or Nothing.

---

On another note, the only issue this pattern addresses is preventing the attempted invocation of a null delegate-reference. Events are [prone to races](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) despite this "fix".

Comment: i would add that when you add method to invocation list you do `+=` which actually replace value of variable. that's why it looks mutable.

Comment: @Andrey: Agreed, I think that syntax throws off many, many developers.

Answer (score 7):

## Update

Here are some diagrams that should hopefully clear up confusion about copying references and assignment.

### First: copying a reference.

[image: x = y]

In the above diagram, the *reference* contained in `y` is copied into `x`. No one's saying the *object* is copied; mind you—they point to the same object.

### Second: assigning a new reference to a variable.

[image: y += "!"]

Forget about the `+=` operator for a moment; what I want to highlight above is that `y` is being assigned a *different* reference, to a *new* object. This does not affect `x` because `x` is its own variable. Remember, only the *reference* (the "address" in the diagram) had been copied to `y`.

### Third: same thing, only to `x`.

[image: x += "?"]

The above diagrams depict `string` objects, only because those are easy to represent graphically. But it's the same thing with delegates (and remember, standard events are just wrappers around delegate fields). You can see how by *copying* the reference in `y` into `x` above, we have created a variable which will not be affected by subsequent assignments to `y`.

That is the whole idea behind the standard `EventHandler` race condition "fix" we're all familiar with.

---

## Original Answer

You are probably confused by this tricky little syntax:

```
someObject.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
```

What's important to realize is that, as [Ani points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892802/net-how-does-the-eventhandler-race-condition-fix-work/4892881#4892881), delegates are immutable reference types (think: just like `string`). Many developers mistakenly think they are mutable because the above code looks like I am "adding" a handler to some mutable list. This isn't so; the `+=` operator is an **assignment operator**: it takes the return value of the `+` operator and assigns it to the variable on the left side.

(Think: `int` is immutable, and yet I can do `int x = 0; x += 1;` right? It's the same thing.)

---

**EDIT**: OK, technically this is not quite right. Here is what really happens. An `event` is actually a wrapper *around* a delegate field that is accessible *only* (to external code) by the `+=` and `-=` operators, which are compiled to calls to `add` and `remove`, respectively. In this way it is very much like a property, which is (typically) a wrapper around a *field*, where accessing the property and calling `=` are compiled to calls to `get` and `set`.

But the point still remains: when you write `+=`, the `add` method that gets called is internally assigning a reference to a *new object* to the internal delegate field. I apologize for oversimplifying this explanation in my initial answer; but the key principle to understand is the same.

<sub>By the way, I am *not* covering custom events where you can put your own logic inside the `add` and `remove` methods. This answer only applies to the "normal" case.</sub>

---

In other words, when you do this...

```
EventHandler handler = SomeEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

...you are indeed copying a *reference* into a variable. Now that reference is in the local variable and won't itself be modified. If it was pointing to an actual object at the time of assignment, then it will continue to point at that same (immutable) object on the next line. If it was *not* pointing to an object (`null`), then it will still not point to an object on the next line.

So if code elsewhere subscribed or unsubscribed to the event using `+=`, what it really did was **change the original reference to point to a completely new object**. The old delegate object is still around, and you've got a reference to it: in your local variable.

Comment: "it takes the return value of the + operator and assigns it to the variable on the left side." - In the context of subscribing to events outside the declaring class, this is not correct. It doesn't mutate (never does) or reassign: it just calls a method: the `add` accessor. The reassignment happens inside the accessor code, assuming a field-like event.

Comment: @Ani: OK, you got me. Technically you're right. I will update the answer to provide a more accurate explanation.

Comment: @Yam: Not quite—I may have oversimplified what happens with events (as Ani pointed out in his comment) but the fact remains that `+=` ultimately results in the assignment of a reference to a new object to a delegate field. See my update; hopefully it clears this up somewhat.

Comment: A follow up: I ILDASM'd some code and it seems that while the add_MyEvent method uses Delegate::Combine, in the method that declares 'handler' to recieve 'MyEvent', it merely puts 'MyEvent' on the stack. This leads me to the final answer, posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that comparing this incident to the 'int' case is probably inherently wrong since even though 'int' is atomic, it is a value type.

But I think we've solved the case:

> Combining operations, such as Combine
>   and Remove, do not alter existing
>   delegates. Instead, such an operation
>   returns a new delegate that contains
>   the results of the operation, an
>   unchanged delegate, or null. A
>   combining operation returns null when
>   the result of the operation is a
>   delegate that does not reference at
>   least one method. A combining
>   operation returns an unchanged
>   delegate when the requested operation
>   has no effect.

[Delegate.CombineImpl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.combineimpl.aspx)
shows the implementation.

I looked over the implementation of Delegate and MulticastDelegate in the .NET 4 source code.
Neither of them declare the += or -= operator. Coming to think of it, in Visual Basic.NET you don't even have them, you use AddHandler, etc...

This means that the C# compiler implements this functionality and that the type doesn't really have anything to do with defining specialized operators.

So this leads me to a logical conclusion which is, when you do:

```
EventHandler handler = MyEvent;
```

the C# compiler translates it to

```
EventHandler handler = EventHandler.Combine(MyEvent)
```

I'm surprised how quickly this question was solved thanks to your help.

Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: That's not correct, it just copies the value of the backing field (a reference) to the local. There's no call to Delegate.Combine there.

Comment: Why would it copy it? I'm reminding you we're talking about a reference type and not a value type.

Comment: The fact that `int` is a value type does not change the semantics of assignment.

Comment: @Yam: There seems to be some misconception here. @Ani is saying the *reference* is copied. This is the same as would happen if you had two references to the same `string` object and then used `+=` on one of them: they would no longer refer to the same object.

Comment: The value of a reference-type variable (in general: expression) is a *reference*. The *reference* is copied.

Comment: There needs to be a clear separation here. Neither Int32 or String define these operators. Moreover, it is known that the C# compiler has specialized behavior when it comes to String concatenation using operators (e.g. it does not create 2 string in "hello " + "world", but only one since it recognizes the pattern). Which means it is not the behavior of the class but of the compiler. Which here led me to believe that the same happens with delegates. Same with integers.