# += operator for Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I know that the **+=** operator will add a method to the invocation list maintained by the Delegate base object, for example

```
using System;

class Program
{

    delegate void MyDelegate(int n);

    void Foo(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", n)
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDelegate d = new MyDelegate(Foo);
        d += Foo; // add Foo again

        d.Invoke(3); // Foo is invoked twice as Foo appears two times in invocation list

    }
}
```

But when I look at MSDN [Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx), [MulticastDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx) I can't find any definition of the **+=** operator. How is it that is just works? Auto-generated compiler magic?

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate of [Why don't I see the += operator overloaded on System.Delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28391414/1364007) but this question has (in my view) better answers.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I agree, I think the duplicate should be marked the other way around.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's not an operator on the delegate type itself, in IL terms - it's defined in the language specification, but you wouldn't find it using reflection. The compiler turns it into a call to [`Delegate.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771). The reverse operation, using `-` or `-=`, uses [`Delegate.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove).

At least, that's how it's implemented when C# targets .NET, as it almost always does. In theory, this is environment-specific - the language specification doesn't require that a compiler uses `Delegate.Combine` or `Delegate.Remove`, and a different environment may not have those methods.

From the C# 5 specification, section 7.8.4 (addition):

> The binary `+` operator performs delegate combination when both operands are of some delegate type `D`. (If the operands have different delegate types, a binding-time error occurs.) If the first operand is `null`, the result of the operation is the value of the second operand (even if that is also `null`). Otherwise, if the second operand is `null`, then the result of the operation is the value of the first operand. Otherwise, the result of the operation is a new delegate instance that, when invoked, invokes the first operand and then invokes the second operand. For examples of delegate combination, see §7.8.5 and §15.4. Since `System.Delegate` is not a delegate type, operator `+` is not defined for it.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms what I mean by "compiler-magic", that the compiler somehow translates the "+=" to something that is defined and readable on MSDN.

Comment: @jensa If that is your definition of "compiler-magic" then many features are compiler magic. For example `==` is not defined on System.Object but the language defines such an operator.

Comment: @mikez: I think it's entirely reasonable to draw a distinction between language-specified operators - including the reference equality `==` as you mention, and also string concatenation - and those which are library-provided, like `DateTime +(DateTIme, Timespan)`.

Comment: @mikez Yeah I guess, I'm coming from a C++ background where very little is language-specified in terms of operators (you get your assignment operator for class types basically), hence my confusion.

Comment: What is the reason that C# delegate is not directly mapped to `System.MulticastDelegate`? Simple types (`int`, `double` etc.), `string` are explicitly defined as aliases to corresponding `System.*` types.

Comment: @JakubLortz: The delegate keyword isn't a type like decimal, string etc. It's used to declare other delegate types, and anonymous methods.

Comment: @MikeZboray Compilers are inherently magic. That's why only wizards create them.

Comment: @jensa In C++ language provides you tons of operators not defined anywhere, but the standard. i.e. all arithmetic  operators on primitives and pointers. Also `operator &`, `operator ->`, `operator ,`. Some have even special meaning (short-circuiting `operator &&`)

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as with `Int32`, `String` etc. The `+` operator is defined implicitly by the language.

You can check the source code of [`Delegate`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,0dd8585ba1833ad7), [`MulticastDelegate`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,0dd8585ba1833ad7), [`Int32`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252) etc. There are no overloads of `operator +` there, that's why it doesn't appear in the MSDN documentation.

From C# language spec, section 7.8.4:

> The predefined addition operators are listed below.
>
> (...)
>
> • Delegate combination. Every delegate type implicitly provides the following predefined operator, where D is the delegate type:
>
> `D operator +(D x, D y);`

There is a difference between simple types and delegates. The C# language specification doesn't require that a delegate is implemented using `System.Delegate`

> 4.2.7 Delegate types
>
> A delegate is a data structure that refers to one or more methods. For instance methods, it also refers to their corresponding object instances.
>   The closest equivalent of a delegate in C or C++ is a function pointer, but whereas a function pointer can only reference static functions, a delegate can reference both static and instance methods. In the latter case, the delegate stores not only a reference to the method’s entry point, but also a reference to the object instance on which to invoke the method.
>   Delegate types are described in §15.

Note that there is no mention of `System.Delegate` there. Compare it with Section 4.1.4 Simple types:

> C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types. The simple types are identified through reserved words, but these reserved words are simply aliases for predefined struct types in the System namespace, as described in the table below.
>
> Reserved word Aliased type
>
> sbyte System.SByte
>   byte    System.Byte
>   short   System.Int16
>   ushort  System.UInt16
>   int System.Int32
>   uint    System.UInt32
>   long    System.Int64
>   ulong   System.UInt64
>   char    System.Char
>   float   System.Single
>   double  System.Double
>   bool    System.Boolean
>   decimal System.Decimal

Or Section 4.2.4 The string type

> (...)
>
> The keyword string is simply an alias for the predefined class System.String.

So resolving the + operator for delegates to `Delegate.Combine` is an implementation detail of C# compilers in .NET framework.