# The difference between += and Delegate.Combine

Tags: c#, delegates

I've built an event system that maintains a `dictionary` of delegates, adds/removes elements to this `dictionary` via generic Subscribe/Unsubscribe methods (which each take an Action of `type` T), and has a Publish method to notify the subscribers when something happens (which also takes an Action of type T). Everything works fine, but I've noticed I cannot use += or -= when adding or removing elements to my `dictionary`, as the types passed into the methods (Action of T), do not match the types stored in the `dictionary` (`Delegate`). The following snippet shows what I can and cannot do.

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> delegates = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> del)
{
    if (delegates.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        // This doesn't work!
        delegates[typeof(T)] += del as Delegate;
        // This doesn't work!
        delegates[typeof(T)] += del;
        // This is ok
        delegates[typeof(T)] = (Action<T>)delegates[typeof(T)] + del;
        // This is ok
        var newDel = (Action<T>)delegates[typeof(T)] + del;
        delegates[typeof(T)] = newDel;
        // This is ok
        del += (Action<T>)delegates[typeof(T)];
        delegates[typeof(T)] = del;
        // This is ok
        delegates[typeof(T)] = Delegate.Combine(delegates[typeof(T)], del);
    }
    else
    {
        delegates[typeof(T)] = del;
    }
}
```

I mostly understand Jon Skeet's answer here [+= operator for Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964927/operator-for-delegate) specifically, this part

*The binary + operator performs delegate combination when both operands are of some delegate type D. (If the operands have different delegate types, a binding-time error occurs.)*

What I don't understand, is this

*The compiler turns it into a call to `Delegate.Combine`. The reverse operation, using - or -=, uses `Delegate.Remove`.*

What exactly is going on when I use += or -=, versus `Delegate.Combine`? What are the differences between the two, making one implementation valid, and another invalid?

Comment: It should be clear - the *compiler* has to know what it's working with to do a `Delegate.Combine`. It doesn't have enough information based on the declared type of `delegates` to make this decision.

Comment: All the ones that work (except the last) work *because* you're inserting casts. Giving the compiler *more* information because you "know better" than it does what the actual type is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the answer you linked, it says:

> Since `System.Delegate` is not a delegate type, operator `+` is not defined for it.

This explains why this does not work (both operands are `Delegate`):

```
delegates[typeof(T)] += del as Delegate;
```

`Delegate.Combine` works because [it is declared like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public static Delegate Combine (params Delegate[] delegates);
```

Note how it accepts parameters of type `Delegate`, instead of a specific delegate type. And it will throw an `ArgumentException` if the delegates are not of the same type.

So the compiler not only changes the `+` operator to `Delegate.Combine`, it also does some type checking! On the other hand, no compile-time type checking is done if you use `Delegate.Combine` directly. `Delegate.Combine` only checks the types at runtime.

All the other lines work because you are casting i.e. telling the compiler what type the delegates are, making both operands of `+` to be of type `Action<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I have a better understanding now. I edited the post slightly to include an additional line that doesn't work, as the cast to Delegate was incorrect/misleading re: my confusion. I think I have a better understanding now of what's going on here, particularly because *System.Delegate is not a delegate type, operator + is not defined for it* Thank you!

Comment: Note that co- and contravariance of generic delegate types has broken some of the type safety here. As an example, `Action<in T>` is contravariant ("`in`") in `T`, and we can create the following example: `Action<ICloneable> act1 = x => x.Clone();
      Action<IConvertible> act2 = x => x.GetTypeCode();

      Action<string> actStr1 = act1; /* OK, contravariance */
      Action<string> actStr2 = act2; /* OK, contravariance */

      actStr1("dummy"); /* works */
      actStr2("dummy"); /* works */

      actStr1 += actStr2; /* does not complain at binding-time, blows up at run-time */`