# Passing functions as arguments using delegates, static methods and multicasting

Tags: c#, delegates

I have been investigating C# delegates and coming from a python angle I wondered what would happen if I treated a static method as a first-class citizen and just passed it directly as an arg without wrapping in a delegate type.

Surprisingly it seemed to work. However when trying to use the same approach with multicasting, it failed with:

`[CS0019] Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'`

My question is what is going on behind the scenes to allow me to pass `staticMethod` directly as an argument and why won't that same process allow me to multicast the method directly in a similar fashion to what I can achieve using the delegate type?

```
using System;

namespace Delegates
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate void Func();

        public static void staticMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In staticMethod()");
        }
        
        public static void executeFunc(Func f)
        {
            f();
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func f = staticMethod;
            
            executeFunc(f);
            
            // why cant' we just pass the static method as a first-class citizen and bypass any delegate creation?'
            executeFunc(staticMethod); // we can - this works
            
            executeFunc(f + f);
            executeFunc(staticMethod + staticMethod); // but this doesn't
        }
    }
}
```

possibly its some sort of implicit cast as the following seemed to work:

```
executeFunc((Func)staticMethod + (Func)staticMethod);
```

Comment: `executeFunc((Func)staticMethod + staticMethod);` is Ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you define `Func` as a delegate, it becomes a [`System.MultiCastDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate), <s>for which the operator + is defined.</s>
edit: ahum, the compiler turns the addition into a `Delegate.Combine`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964976).

your static method is just a normal function, i.e. a `method group`. And no addition operation is defined for `method group` types. (what would it do?)

By typing `executeFunc((Func)staticMethod + (Func)staticMethod);` You are explicitly casting the method group types to delegate types... and the compiler knows what to do again.

edit: By the way, note the existence of [`System.Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action) which is the library equal of your `Func`.

Comment: `executeFunc((Func)staticMethod + staticMethod);` is Ok.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy true, but then the first argument is no longer a method group... it has been explicitly cast to a delegate.

Comment: good point on the System Action delegate, also I can see that a Func delegate is in there as well for when you have args and returns