# null event += doesn't cause an error. Why is this `null +=` not an error?

Tags: c#, events, null, delegates, field

Running the following

```cs
delegate void GreetDelegateType();

public class Program {
    static GreetDelegateType GreetDelegate;
    static event GreetDelegateType GreetEvent;
    static void GreetInEnglish() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (GreetDelegate == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("GreetDelegate is null");
            GreetDelegate += GreetInEnglish;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("GreetDelegate is not null");
        }
        GreetDelegate();
        
        if (GreetEvent == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("GreetEvent is null");
            GreetEvent += GreetInEnglish;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("GreetEvent is not null");
        }
        GreetEvent();
    }
}
```

prints

```
GreetDelegate is null
Hello!
GreetEvent is null
Hello!
```

to the console. Since `GreetDelegate` and `GreetEvent` are each `null`, why do the lines `GreetDelegate += GreetInEnglish;` and `GreetEvent += GreetInEnglish;` not cause errors? `null += <anything>` feels like it should cause errors. Does the `<null event> +=`  call the `add` method of the `event` even though the event is `null`?

---

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#93-default-values) explains how `GreetDelegate` and `GreetEvent` were each assigned `null`.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964976) by Jon Skeet to +[= operator for Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33964927): += is *not an operator on the delegate type itself, in IL terms - it's defined in the language specification, but you wouldn't find it using reflection. The compiler turns it into a call to [`Delegate.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771). The reverse operation, using - or -=, uses `Delegate.Remove`.*

Comment: And checking the docs for [`Delegate.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771) we see *If the delegates array contains entries that are `null`, those entries are ignored.*.  So that's why `GreetDelegate += GreetInEnglish` doesn't cause an error.  Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964976) also quotes the C# 5 spec which explicitly states that `null` values are allowed when combining delegates.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dbc Yes! Thank you! So to recap... Is the following correct? The signature of `Delgate.Combine` is `public static Delegate? Combine (Delegate? a, Delegate? b)`. So, for example, `GreetDelegate += GreetInEnglish` is rewritten as `GreetDelegate = Delegate.Combine(GreetDelegate, GreetInEnglish)`? `GreetInEnglish` is a method group, so it's implicitly cast to a delegate? To fit the signature of `Delegate.Combine`? Best!

Answer (score 1):

C# uses the += operator as the Combine method and the -= operator as the Remove method to implement delegate operations.

The += operator works like this:
A new delegate with an invocation list that concatenates the invocation lists of a and b in that order. Returns a if b is null, returns b if a is a null reference, and returns a null reference if both a and b are null references.

More information you can see below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=net-8.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.combine?view=net-8.0